# Sorting list of tuples (Python)

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am new in python and for practice reasons, I am trying to solve the following task:

Given a list of tuples
`A = [(17, 8), (17, 12), (7, 2), (9, 15), (9, 17), (1, 4), (3, 9), (12, 14)]`

My goal is: to sort in **(n log n)** time in descending order the list according to the first element of the set and if the first element of two sets are the same, sorting in descending order according to the second element. --> `x <= x', y <= y'`

So, I want to get the result:
`A = [(17, 12), (17, 8), (12, 14), (9, 17), (9, 15), (7, 2), (3, 9), (1, 4)]`

I have tried using the following code:

`A.sort(reverse = True, key=lambda x: x[0] )`

But it just sorts according to the first element and I do know if it is in *n log n* time.

Could you please help me with that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort based on both values, remove the key function:

```
>>> A.sort(reverse = True)
>>> A
[(17, 12), (17, 8), (12, 14), (9, 17), (9, 15), (7, 2), (3, 9), (1, 4)]
```

And yes, Python sorts in `O(n log n)`, for more, check out [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) on Wikipedia, the algorithm Python uses for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Python's inbuilt sorted() method with a comparator function(Similar to C++) will work

```
sorted(tup, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are naturally sorted by the first element, then the second:

```py
A.sort(reverse = True)
```

Output as requested.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
A = [(17, 8), (17, 12), (7, 2), (9, 15), (9, 17), (1, 4), (3, 9), (12, 14)]

reverse_sorted = []

for item in reversed(sorted(A)):
    reverse_sorted.append(item)
    
print(reverse_sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

As to add to the other's excellent answers. Search on Google with "python list sort time complexity" will return for you what you seek regarding python's sort time complexities (that others have already written above).

In addition, if you need to move away from using python's inbuilt sort function. There are many different [sorting algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/) created over the years that you can recreate that have the desired time complexities. It would be a good "training" exercise if you're new to programming in general.